# Table View Controller and TextField Inside ModalView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, tableview, modalviewcontroller

I try to add tableView and TextField inside the ModalView. I do so. I create new View Controller and give for it

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol UYLModalViewControllerDelegate

-(void) buttonDonePassed :(NSArray *) variables;

@end

@interface UYLModalViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
{ 

    id<UYLModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

    IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

    NSMutableArray *cellsArray;
    //UITextField *textField;



}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UYLModalViewControllerDelegate>    delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;


@end
```

And IN .m File I create functions

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [cellsArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [cellsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Configure the cell.

    return cell;
}
```

and ViewDidiLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(buttonPassed:)];

    //UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    //[self]
    cellsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil];
    [tblView reloadData];
}
```

But my program don't go to the TableViewDelegate methods (such as cellforrowAtIndexPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `UYLModalViewController` as the `tableView`'s `delegate` and `datasource`.

---

It looks like you are using `Interface Builder` so you need to:

1. `control + click` on the tableView and drag it across to the `File's Owner`
2. Then select `datasource` from the HUD menu.
3. Then repeat the process but selecting `delegate`

**Note**
Your controller should also conform to `UITableViewDatasource` giving you:

```
@interface UYLModalViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource>
```

---

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

---

If you prefer you can do this in code in `viewDidLoad` or any place where you create the `tableView` if you do it programatically.

```
self.tableView.delegate   = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: Oy, yes it work=)  Thanks A lot. Can You help me with little problem with my XCode. If I edit the same file in standart editor and in assistant editor they give me different files. But the names of files are the same. And I can't understand what file will be compiled((

Comment: Are you sure they are the same files? The companion editor defaults to showing the `.h` file in one window and the `.m` in the other.

Comment: yes I am sure, because I see the same name of files. For example When I click to file in progect solution I see One version of it, When I edit .nib file and use assistant editor I see the another(

Comment: Maybe you should start a new question with more detail. Are you sure you are using the assistant editor and you are not on the version editor which could be showing an older version of the doc if you use version control.